# Running async function locally using NodeJS in Windows 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, async-await, environment-variables

I am struggling to run an async function taken from a Google example alongside the Environment Variables on Windows 10. I have created a bucket at GCS and uploaded my .raw file.

I then created a .env file which contains the following

HOST=localhost

PORT=3000

GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=GDeveloperKey.json

Doing this in AWS Lambda is just a case of wrapping the code within `exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {`

How can I emulate the same locally in Windows 10?

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech');

// Creates a client
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// const gcsUri = 'gs://my-bucket/audio.raw';
// const encoding = 'Encoding of the audio file, e.g. LINEAR16';
// const sampleRateHertz = 16000;
// const languageCode = 'BCP-47 language code, e.g. en-US';

const config = {
  encoding: encoding,
  sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
  languageCode: languageCode,
};

const audio = {
  uri: gcsUri,
};

const request = {
  config: config,
  audio: audio,
};

// Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
// can wait for now, or get its result later.
const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
// Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
const [response] = await operation.promise();
const transcription = response.results
  .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
```

Comment: `(async function () { /* you code here */ })();`

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your `await` statements into an immediately-invoked async function.

Ex:

```
(async () => {
  // Detects speech in the audio file. This creates a recognition job that you
  // can wait for now, or get its result later.
  const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
  // Get a Promise representation of the final result of the job
  const [response] = await operation.promise();
  const transcription = response.results
    .map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
})();
```